# Synchronicity of WPF view-model binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Do updates to UI elements that are precipitated by programmatic changes to CLR objects to which they are bound happen synchronously or asynchronously?

I have something akin to the following code:

```
checkbox.Checked -= CheckboxStateChangeHandler;
checkbox.UnChecked -= CheckboxStateChangeHandler;

CheckboxViewModel.IsChecked = true;

checkbox.Checked += CheckboxStateChangeHandler;
checkbox.UnChecked += CheckboxStateChangeHandler;
```

Can I be certain that the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events which will be raised by `checkbox` in response to me setting the viewmodel property to which it is bound will *definitely* always fire *before* the event handler is re-registered?

Comment: Yes. Still, forget the event-based winforms-like approach. There is no need for that in WPF. What do you want `Checked` and `UnChecked` for?

Comment: I'm using them to save the changed options represented by those Checkboxes to the database. What's the alternative? Would this be better handled by custom Commands?

Comment: the UI has nothing to do with Databases. Your ViewModel should pass the `IsChecked` value to an underlying Data Model, which should take care of the responsibility of storing data, etc. You don't need any UI-related events for that. Simple DataBinding (which I understand you already have in place) should be enough.

Comment: In my real app I actually have an ObservableCollection of CheckboxViewModel objects (which implement INotifyPropertyChanged). Databinding obviously ensures these objects are updated in response to user interaction, but I don't know how to make the rest of my app aware of the change in order to save it to the model without putting event handlers on the UI.

Comment: Your VM should "know" the Model, and update it as needed.

Comment: You're right, of course. The complication in my case is that there isn't a direct correlation between the ViewModel and database fields - each checkbox represents a "tag" which not only sets/unsets tags but also displays the status of that tag across one or more selected items (true, false or indeterminate). It has since occurred to me to use a ValueConverter to help manage this more complex relationship, though, so I can ditch the event handlers.